# Can I use NavLInk or Link to link to an element?

Tags: html, reactjs, anchor

This is probably a problem of me not knowing what to search, but here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

When using traditional anchor tags I can easily link to a section `<a href="#section">` by invoking the ID of the section `<section id="section">`.

When I try to put `#section` into the `to` attribute(?) of Link or NavLink, it does nothing. It shows the same in the browser as when I use an `<a>` tag - when I hover it shows "localhost:3000/#section" - but when I click it, it doesn't do anything. When I change the tag to an anchor tag w/ "href" instead of "to", it works just fine.

Should I just use anchor tags in my nav menu instead of NavLink, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/394 https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Konrad Linkowski for the answer.

Since his answer was just a couple links, but they gave me the info I needed, I will expound here:

github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/394
npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link

Basically, if you want to use hashtag links like I described above, you need to install react-router-hash link (`npm i react-router-hash-link`). Then import HashLink and/or NavHashLink (`import { Hashlink, NavHashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';`) in the file you are wanting to add the links in.

Alternatively, you can just use anchor tags (`<a href....`), although this is usually just reserved for links to locations outside your app, and will complicate using the active class for your nav links.